# CodeIgniter 3 - function search value in database return error 500

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

I try search value (ean) and if exist in database  return title product assigned to this ean.

I've 2 tables:

```
products

product_details
```

in products table I have EAN and in `product_details` I've   title.

```
products.id  = product_details.product_id
```

View:

```
            <div class="form-group">

            <label><?= trans("search"); ?></label>

            <input type="text" id="input_product_exist" class="form-control" placeholder="<?= trans("category_name"); ?>">

            <div id="product_search_result" class="category-search-result"></div>

        </div>
```

Script in view:

```
<script>
$(document).on("input", "#input_product_exist", function () {

    var val = $(this).val();

    val = val.trim();

    if (val.length > 1) {

        var data = {

            "ean": val,

            "sys_lang_id": sys_lang_id

        };

        data[csfr_token_name] = $.cookie(csfr_cookie_name);

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: base_url + "ajax_controller/search_products",

            data: data,

            success: function (response) {

                var obj = JSON.parse(response);

                if (obj.result == 1) {

                    document.getElementById("product_search_result").innerHTML = obj.content;

                }

            }

        });

    } else {

        document.getElementById("product_search_result").innerHTML = "";

    }

});
```

ajax_controller:

```
 //search products
public function search_products()
{
    $ean = $this->input->post('ean', true);
    $products = $this->category_model->search_products_by_ean($product_ean);
    $content = '<ul>';
    if (!empty($products)) {
        foreach ($products as $item) {
            $content .= '<li>' . html_escape($item->name) . ' - <strong>' . trans("id") . ': ' . $item->id . '</strong></li>';
        }
        $content .= '</ul>';
    } else {
        $content = '<p class="m-t-15 text-center text-muted">' . trans("no_records_found") . '</p>';
    }
    $data = array(
        'result' => 1,
        'content' => $content
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

category_model.php

```
    //search products by ean
public function search_products_by_ean($product_ean)
{
    $this->db->select('products.id, product_details.title as name');
    $this->db->join('product_details', 'product_details.product_id = products.id');
    $this->db->like('name', clean_str($product_ean));
    //$this->db->where('visibility', 1);
    //$this->db->order_by('categories.parent_id');
    $this->db->order_by('name');
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Now I try start search: white page.

I check in log console:

```
jquery.min.js:4          POST https://thisismywebsite.com/ajax_controller/search_products 500
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ add-product:1581
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

@update:

I think still I have any issue in step 3, category_model/search_products_by_ean

Here I  build working query in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT products.ean, product_details.title  FROM products INNER JOIN product_details ON products.id = product_details.product_id;
```

and I get correct output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> @update
>
> you can enable php errors with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

for view current error not 500

in ajax controller your must send $ean not $product_ean

```
 //search products
public function search_products()
{
    $ean = $this->input->post('ean', true);
  //  $products = $this->category_model->search_products_by_ean($product_ean);
    $products = $this->category_model->search_products_by_ean($ean);//istead $product_ean
    $content = '<ul>';
    if (!empty($products)) {
        foreach ($products as $item) {
            $content .= '<li>' . html_escape($item->name) . ' - <strong>' . trans("id") . ': ' . $item->id . '</strong></li>';
        }
        $content .= '</ul>';
    } else {
        $content = '<p class="m-t-15 text-center text-muted">' . trans("no_records_found") . '</p>';
    }
    $data = array(
        'result' => 1,
        'content' => $content
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: can you please check my update topic. I  change this in ajax controller but still I get error 500. I think I've any issue in category_model with build sql query. I paste working sql query, Could you please review this in category_model, maybe you found issue and you can help me resolve  this query (rewrite to CI3)

Comment: I try     //search products by name
    public function search_products_by_ean($ean)
    {
   $this->db->select('products.ean, product_details.title as name');
   $this->db->join('product_details', 'product_details.product_id = products.id');
   $this->db->like('name');
        $query = $this->db->get('products');
        return $query->result();
    } but still I get error 500

Comment: I try also this        //search products by name
    public function search_products_by_ean($ean)
    {
   $this->db->select('products.ean, product_details.title as name');
   $this->db->join('product_details', 'product_details.product_id = products.id');
   $this->db->like('name', clean_str($ean));
        $query = $this->db->get('products');
        return $query->result();
    }